# PayPal in Magento with Authorization option: how long the authorization is valid?

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, paypal

I'm using PayPal Express Checkout with the **Authorization** option for the **Payment Action**:

[image]

Scenario:

- An user makes an order, paying with PayPal, so a new order will be created in Magento.
- The order contains two products: `A` and `B`.

**Question n. 1**: how long can I wait to complete the order, creating invoices and getting money from the customer's PayPal account? If the order is placed on **19 nov**, can I confirm the payment and get moneys 30 days after?

**Question n. 2**: if the order is placed on **19 nov** and the same day I create the invoice and I get the payment just for product `A`, how long can I wait to get the payment also for product `B`? Can I get money for `A` on **19 nov** and money for `B` on **19 dic**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming or code. This question would be better suited to [the Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) where questions like this are on-topic.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I posted the question here since it is more about PayPal than Magento. The answer depends on how PayPal works, not really much on Magento.

Comment: fair enough and that may be true, however it's off topic for Stackoverflow since it's not related to code